# Не получается импортировать подмодуль QtWidgets из библиотеки PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, импорт

Начал изучать PyQt5. При попытке импортировать нужные модули -

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
```

Возникает ошибка -

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWidgets' from partially initialized module 'PyQt5' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

PyQt5 устанавливался через pip

IDE - VS Code, версия python - 3.10.6

> **Дополнено позже** - мой проект был назван так же, как и библиотека (PyQt5.py) и поэтому появлялась ошибка. Для устранения подобной проблемы переименуйте проект на название, отличное от "PyQt5".

Answer (score 0):

Так надо:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
```